# Underline property of textbox not working like the others

Tags: vba, excel

I simply want to underline some text in a worksheet textbox using VBA, from a specific character to another. It should be extremely simple, and I can do it without problem with Bold and Italic.

I have the following sub

```
Sub ew()
    Dim txt1 As Shape
    Set txt1 = Sheet1.Shapes("txt_1")
    txt1.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Bold and Underline this"

    txt1.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    txt1.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Italic = True
    txt1.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Underline = True
End Sub
```

The code fails on the last line, which is extremely strange because it worked for the 2 previous lines. the error (1004) says something like "Impossible to define the Underline function of the Font property".

To recreate the problem, take my sub to a new Excel document and create a textbox named "txt_1", that's all you need to run it.

If anyone has any idea why it fails, please help!

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/underline-specific-words-in-text-box/cf2bf9ac-a1f3-42bf-a51e-f530ae907a06?auth=1 does this help you?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the Underline style.  Taking your last line
`txt1.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle`

Comment: Ah.. I feel like a noob now :)

Comment: Here's a link to other styles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215913%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use `TextFrame2` for underline

`txt1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.UnderlineStyle = msoUnderlineSingleLine`

Comment: `TextFrame2` gives you more UnderLine styles, if you want to get real fancy. :)