# How can I reference a label on a Worksheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, label

I have a series of labels on a worksheet (not a userform) which I want to refer to programmatically.

Specifically I want to underline the text in any label that I choose.

I am struggling to find the correct syntax as all the examples refer to userforms.  I thought that if I created a label variable, I could assign a label to this variable and then set its underline property to true.

Along the lines of:-

```
Dim lbl as Label

Set lbl = ActiveSheet.Labels("lblTest")  

(or Set lbl = ActiveSheet.Controls("lblTest"))

lbl.Font.Underline = True
```

but I can't find the right syntax.

Update 10/01/21

I've got this working now with this code

```
  Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
  
  Set lbl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("lblTest").Object

  lbl.Font.Underline = True
```

Using the `.Object` reference seems to allow you to get at any property of the label.

I adapted the code in this post:-

[Edit Form Control Label Caption on VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713077/edit-form-control-label-caption-on-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the Shapes collection. This link should put you on the right track:

[Underline property of textbox not working like the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401439/underline-property-of-textbox-not-working-like-the-others)

Comment: I stil haven't quite got there.  This is my latest attempt:-

    Dim lbl As Shape
  
  Set lbl = ActiveSheet.Shapes("lblTest")
  
  lbl.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Underline = msoUnderlineSingleLine

But I just get 'Object doesn't support this property or method'  even though I followed the Object prompts to get there!

Comment: You used =msoUnderlineSingleLine, which is for TextFrame2. You're using TextFrame, so try =xlUnderlineStyleSingle.

Comment: I have tried various constants for the underline and none of them work.  They are just named integer constants, so it should make no difference which you use.

I've tried both the form label class with the Shapes collection and the ActiveX label class with the OLEObjects collection and I've also tried it with text boxes without any success.

This leads me to think that I'm missing something more fundamental.  I could just do this with a Select Case to deal with all the possibilities, but that wouldn't be particularly elegant and I don't like giving up!

Comment: Are you even able to `.Select` the shape in question?

Comment: I can use  `.Select` and things like `.Height` and `.Width`, but still can't get to the font properties.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your current code?